# update woocommerce cart that uses a custom function

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, cart, elementor

I have created the following code.
Each (shipping) box can contain up to 20kg of items. Then it moves on to the next box. It is also showing how full a box is by using a percentage. This is working fine.

But when adding an item with Ajax, the code is not updating. The code only updates when there's a reload of the page.

Please advise.

```
                /**
                 * Display menu cart icon text based on box number, item count, and weight.
                 */
                function display_menu_cart_icon_text( $content, $widget ) {
                    // Check if the widget is the menu cart module.
                    if ( 'woocommerce-menu-cart' === $widget->get_name() ) {
                        // Get the total weight of items in the cart.
                        $total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

                        // Define the weight limit per box.
                        $weight_limit = 20; // Specify the weight limit in your desired unit.

                        // Calculate the number of boxes based on the total weight.
                        $box_number = ceil( $total_weight / $weight_limit );

                        // Calculate the weight remaining in the current box.
                        $box_weight_remaining = $weight_limit - ( $total_weight % $weight_limit );

                        // Determine if the current box is full.
                        $is_box_full = $box_weight_remaining === $weight_limit;

                        // Calculate the percentage of the current box filled.
                        $box_percentage = $is_box_full ? 100 : round( ( ( $weight_limit - $box_weight_remaining ) / $weight_limit ) * 100 );

                        // Get the number of items in the cart.
                        $item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

                        // Set the default text for an empty cart.
                        $cart_icon_text = 'Box 1:<br> leeg';

                        if ( $item_count > 0 ) {
                            // Generate the text for a non-empty cart.
                            if ( $is_box_full ) {
                                $cart_icon_text = 'Box ' . $box_number . ': Box is full';
                            } else {
                                $cart_icon_text = 'Box ' . $box_number . ':<br>' . $box_percentage . '%';
                            }
                        }

                        // Wrap the cart icon text in a <div> with class .elementor-menu-cart__text.
                        $cart_icon_text = '<div class="elementor-menu-cart__text">' . $cart_icon_text . '</div>';

                        // Find the Elementor menu cart icon wrapper.
                        $menu_icon_wrapper = '<div class="elementor-menu-cart__toggle_wrapper">';

                        // Insert the cart icon text before the menu icon wrapper.
                        $content = str_replace( $menu_icon_wrapper, $cart_icon_text . $menu_icon_wrapper, $content );
                    }

                    return $content;
                }

                // Hook the function to the menu cart module.
                add_filter( 'elementor/widget/render_content', 'display_menu_cart_icon_text', 10, 2 );
```

I don't know how to update the code...